# How to set up Facebook Javascript SDK on angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I tried to set up Facebook SDK in my code but it always returns an error.
What I did first is put my code in my index page below the angular.module:

```
var fbApi = angular.module('fbApi',['ngRoute']);
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    FB.init({ 
                      appId: 'api-id',

                      xfbml: true,
                      version: 'v2.6'
                    });
                };
            (function(d, s, id){
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Then i have also created a service:

```
function fbApi () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
            FB.api('/video_id', {
                fields: 'format'
            }, function(response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    deferred.reject('Error occured');
                } else {
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                }
            });
            return deferred.promise;
     }
```

But it returns an error saying FB is undefined or not a function. Did I forgot something very important?

Comment: You can't call FB before fbAsyncInit is called

Comment: but where should i place the fbAsynInit??

Comment: Doesn't matter where you place it.

Comment: fbAsyncInit is in my index page and i call fb after the fbAsyncInit in my service script. still the same problem, FB not defined

Comment: The Facebook SDK will call fbAsyncInit when FB exists. You call FB.api before that happens

Comment: can you give me some example??